# How to diagnose broken gnome 3 desktop?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-session

Under 19.10, after removing some unused (I thought so) gnome-shell extensions and logging out, I now **can't start Gnome** anymore.

If I choose a wayland session, it simply goes back to gdm after a short while.

If I choose an X session, I get a screen saying "Oh no ! Something has gone wrong" and a single "Log out" button. Hitting the button brings me back to gdm.

Notice that :

- this is related to my (main) user, as a newly created user can start a gnome session
- a freshly installed xfce4 desktop does not start either, nor a Ubuntu session

I'm not sure where to look to diagnose and hopefully recover from the problem. Any idea ?

Comment: I finally found a workaround by moving .local/share/gnome-shell/ out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried log in in the other user and see the dependecies of gnome on synaptic?

I found this:

[gnome site](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-installation-dependencies.html.en)

Maybe if you log in in the other user and satisfy the dependencies of the gnome desktop(what you have deleted/unistalled) it will go to back status.

Another option could be delete all the things called gnome in synpatic, and try reinstall gnome via console or synpatic package manager.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

that is the code for install via console

I hope you could get some help of this, and sorry for my english, in not very good :)

Comment: Thanks @Musko for the advice. In fact gnome desktop install is ok, as it will start with my second user. Problem is really related to the settings. The extensions I removed are gnome-shell extensions, not using apt or synaptic...